# Преобразовать данные из MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Есть класс `Person`, в нем есть поле `name`. Я записываю эти данные в Mongo, но на выходе, хочу получать не записанные по 1-у классы, а все поля `name` из них, но в `List<String>`. Вот код

```
@RestController
public class Post_Get {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    private List<String> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostMapping("api/names")
    public void post (@RequestParam("username") String name) {
        Person person = new Person(name);
        personRepository.save(person);
    }

    @GetMapping("api/names")
    public List<Person> get () {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: создайте метод `List<String> findAllName()` и реализуйте его. в чем конкретно у вас проблема?

Comment: Вывод получается в формате `{name: "John"}, {name:"Piter"}`, а мне надо например просто `John, Peter` и тд...

Comment: для этого создайте метод `List<String> findAllName()` и реализуйте его, который вернет только имена

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("api/names")
public List<String> getNames() {
    return personRepository.findAll()
                           .stream()
                           .map(Person::getName)
                           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Или без лишней конвертаций

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {
    Stream<Person> findByNameNotNull();
}

@GetMapping("api/names")
public List<String> getNames() {
    return personRepository.findByNameNotNull()
                           .map(Person::getName)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```